# Cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry' to 'Tweetinvi.Models.IUserIdentifier'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to use the x:name of the entry field to store the username of a twitter user and then using it for accessing the feeds. But I'm facing this error:  cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry' to 'Tweetinvi.Models.IUserIdentifier'. What to do?

**XAML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App7.Views.AnalysisPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Entry x:Name="twitteruser_entry" Placeholder="@Username"></Entry>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content> </ContentPage>
```

**XAML.CS File**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Tweetinvi;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Tweetinvi.Models.Webhooks;

namespace App7.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AnalysisPage : ContentPage
    {
        public AnalysisPage ()
        {
            var user_identifier = twitteruser_entry; //this is where i'm getting the error.

            var User = (dynamic)null;
            var authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();



            var tweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline(user_identifier, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using? It seems you're trying to cast the actual Entry to a Tweetinvi.Models.IUserIdentifier which Entry does not implement.

Comment: @JohannPérez please check once.

Comment: From what I see on the Timeline source https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/a5dd374d951c25b29f9770927a102da07fb28afd/Tweetinvi/Timeline.cs non of the GetUserTimeline methods receives an Entry. You could use `public static IEnumerable<ITweet> GetUserTimeline(string userScreenName, int maximumTweets = 40` if you change `var user_identifier = twitteruser_entry;` to `var user_identifier = twitteruser_entry.Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is failing because it is trying all of the overloads and only returns the error on the last one.

Given the name of the field I am going to assume that the user is going to enter their username into the field. In this case you are probably wanting this overload

```
public static IEnumerable<ITweet> GetUserTimeline(string userScreenName, IUserTimelineParameters userTimelineParameters)
```

If this is the case, you need to get the text from the entry and pass it to that method.

```
var tweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline(user_identifier.Text, 10);
```